# Storing arrays in data and showing it in handlebars

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, request, handlebars.js

Need some help in the snippet below.
**Goal:** How to store array in data.nick and show it in handlebars(each separately)?

**JS:**

```
function(data, callback){
            var URL = 'url';
            request(URL, function(err, response, body) {
                if(response.statusCode == 200){
                var json = JSON.parse(body);
                    for(var i = 0; i < json['nick'].length; i++){
                        var s = [];
                        s = json['nick'][i].id;
                    }
                    data.nick = s;
                    console.log(data.nick);
                    callback(null,data);
                }
            });
        },
```

**Issue:** `data.nick` is storing only the last object queried while `s` is an array.

---

**Edit:**

Array fixed, the question for now is how to show each of the items in html using express-handlebars

I was trying to use `{{#each info.nick}}`, `{{#list info.nick}}`, `{{info.nick.[0]}}` etc. but it's not working.

> I've got array `[ 432, 3, 104, 222, 30, 11, 62, 421, 17, 412 ]` and I would show each of it using express-handlebars.

Comment: `s = json['nick'][i].id` is overwriting the empty array with just the value of the `id` item. Even if it wasn't you keep resetting the array to be empty on every iteration, so only the last item will be shown.

Comment: Hmm i've called console.log(s); and it's showing me 10 objects that i want.

Comment: so why , u  ask this question ?

Comment: Bcs i don't know how to connect it with data.nick = s; and i don't know how to show each of 10 items in handlebars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reseting the array `s` to be empty on each loop. Along with that you are not adding an item to the array, rather you are overwriting the array with a single value of `json['nick'][i].id`. That's why you are only seeing the last item, because all the other ones where lost. You will want to define you array before the for-loop and use `.push()` to add an item to it:

```
...
var s = [];
for(var i = 0; i < json['nick'].length; i++){
    s.push(json['nick'][i].id);
}
data.nick = s;
...
```

Note that `data.nick = s` is a shallow copy.

Comment: Worked aswell. Any ideas how to show each of item in data.nick using handlebars?

{{#each info.nick}}
{{/each}} is not working

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.map` to ge only `id` attribute 
:

```
function(data, callback){
            var URL = 'url';
            request(URL, function(err, response, body) {
                if(response.statusCode == 200){
                     var json = JSON.parse(body);
                    data.nick = json['nick'].map(function(e,i){return e.id});
                    console.log(data.nick);
                    callback(null,data);
                }
            });
        },
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working, but the second problem is how to show each of ID in handlebars.

info: data and i'm trying to {{info.nick}} and {{#each info.nick}}but it's not working.